# plotting multiple columns on same chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot multiple column graphs on the same chart, stacked on each other. [This is an example of desired output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H03O.png)

Each colored column segment represents percent of team to have reached a given level by the end of the given month. So it's like 4 separate column charts stacked. I think this is different than grouped and stacked, but may be mistaken.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: It is a stacked column chart. You can see an example of it from the Highcharts website http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of stacked and column range. There are a few caveats with this in that you have to have a category for your `yAxis` which causes some funkiness with how you set your series' data values. I opted for one method and I am sure there are others. What I did was first set the chart type to `'columnrange'`:

```
chart: {
  type: 'columnrange'
},
```

Then I set up the `yAxis` properties to use categories:

```
yAxis: {
  categories: ['Level 0', 'Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'],
```

Since the offset of the category is in-between the tick marks of the axis I removed them and set the start position to not be on the tick:

```
  startOnTick: false,
  min: .5,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
```

Up next I have to set the format of the [labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter) (essentially just hiding the first label):

```
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      var label = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
      if (!this.isFirst) {
        return label;
      }
    }
  },
```

Now I create [`plotLines`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines) to mimic the gridlines with the last one a different color to denote the "Target":

```
  plotLines: [{
    color: '#e6e6e6',
    width: 1,
    value: 1
  }, {
    color: '#e6e6e6',
    width: 1,
    value: 2
  }, {
    color: 'red',
    width: 2,
    value: 3,
    label: {
      text: 'Target'
    }
  }]
```

Now I setup the `plotOptions` for this chart. Note that the `stacking` parameter is not listed in the API as being part of the `columnrange` type but it still functions (as of this answer using v5.0):

```
plotOptions: {
  columnrange: {
    stacking: true
  }
},
```

Okay, almost there. I then set up the series data:

```
series: [{
  name: 's1',
  data: [
    [0, .64],
    [0, .9],
    [0, 1]
  ]
}, {
  name: 's2',
  data: [
    [null, null],
    [1, 1.1],
    [1.0, 1.5]
  ]
}, {
  name: 's3',
  data: [
    [null, null],
    [null, null],
    [2.0, 2.5]
  ]
}]
```

The important part of the data values is that each "level" is a whole integer such that Level 1 is from 0 to 1 and Level 2 is from 1 to 2 and Level 3 is from 2 to 3. This works out good as you try to determine your percentage in each level for each month as they are still in uniform increments.

I did not modify the tooltip as you gave no specs on that.

Sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2wxoyyp/) and full code:

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
      categories: ['Level 0', 'Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'],
      startOnTick: false,
      min: .5,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var label = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
          if (!this.isFirst) {
            return label;
          }
        }
      },
      plotLines: [{
        color: '#e6e6e6',
        width: 1,
        value: 1
      }, {
        color: '#e6e6e6',
        width: 1,
        value: 2
      }, {
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        value: 3,
        label: {
          text: 'Target'
        }
      }]
    },
    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        stacking: true
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
      name: 's1',
      data: [
        [0, .64],
        [0, .9],
        [0, 1]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 's2',
      data: [
        [null, null],
        [1, 1.1],
        [1.0, 1.5]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 's3',
      data: [
        [null, null],
        [null, null],
        [2.0, 2.5]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```